# Sara has a white, a pink, a blue, a yellow and an orange flower.

Tags: combinatorics

Sara has a white, a pink, a blue, a yellow and an orange flower.
She wants to plant these $5$ flowers in a row, but she does not want the orange flower to be the first
or the last flower in the row.
How many different arrangements are possible?

Comment: 3*2*1 this my answer < any one give me hint

Comment: **Hint:** if you show what you've tried or what is giving you trouble, the question might get more upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

There are three positions in which to place the orange flower (the middle three): that gives $3$ ways to plant that flower. The remaining four spots can be filled in $4!$ ways: That gives us, in total: $$3\times 4! = 3 \cdot (4 \cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1) = 72$$ arrangements in which to plant the flowers.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is! Does this make sense?

Comment: @moamen Note that this is the same _value_ as MITjanitor's answer gives - they're two different approaches to getting that number, but the fact that both give the same value is a nice double-check on both.

Comment: Note that $3 \times 4! = (5! - 2\cdot 4!) = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3!= 3 \cdot 4\cdot 3! = 3\times 4! = 72$

Answer (score 4):

I generally like to count the number of "bad" ways to arrange the flowers, then subtract these from the *total* number of ways to arrange them ($5!$).

There are $4!$ different combinations with the orange flower in the first spot. Similarly there are $4!$ ways which put the orange flower in the last spot. So the total would then be $5!-2\cdot 4!$.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Rule of Product**

Choosing a place for orange flower = 3 choices (as it can have three choices)

For rest flowers, 4 choices are left (leaving the occupied space by orange flower, hence $4\choose 4$ cases).

$\implies$ $\frac{4!}{4!.0!} . 4!$

(4! Is multiplied as the rest four flowers can be permute in themselves)

Hence, total number of arrangements = $3.4!$ = $72$

Comment: there was a typo. edited now.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is an exception on the first and last places of the order, start with these positions.

1) Number of possibilities for first position = $4 $ (No Orange)

2) Number of possibilities for last position = $3$ (No Orange)

3) Number of possibilities for the other $3$ positions = $3!$ (Orange included)

Total arrangements = $4.3.3!$ = $72$

Answer (score -3):

My answer is $3\times 2\times 1$ which is $6$.

Comment: Not the right answer. If you show more work, someone might be able to point out where the problem lies.

Comment: Seems like you are arranging $3$ flowers in between two orange ones. Which is incorrect.